# Sqlite3 Mass update elements in quite quick time

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I am trying to update mass fields in sqlite3 database but I still don't know what is the problem. I searched around but nothing was connected with my problem.
Here is my code:

```
public void highlightSearchListItemsByPositions(List<Integer> results) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTION_IS_SEARCH_RESULT_ITEM, OPTION_YES);

    db.beginTransaction();

    for (int position : results) {
        db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_LAW, contentValues, KEY_POSITION + " = ?", new String[]{position + ""});
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

}
```

When I check by adb, the column KEY_OPTION_IS_SEARCH_RESULT_ITEMS is totally filled with zeros. OPTION_YES is string "1"

Comment: What is the data type of the values in the KEY_POSITION column?

Comment: KEY_POSITION is type of integer, why?

Comment: What is the return value of the `update` method?

Comment: let's say the current text is with POSITION 0 and _ID = 0 it returns me 8

Comment: If that is what `update` actually returns, then the records did get updated, and I cannot help you with your problem.

Comment: ok, last question, is this calling methods flow - I mean begin `transaction>for loop with update>transaction successful>end transaction` is ok?